# What functionalities can I access by WebKit?

Tags: android, webkit

Would I be able to access the following information by HTML 5?

- GPS position
- [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) device list
- [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) network list
- Contacts
- Calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use "wrapper" to improve HTML 5 functionalities. That's all you can do.
No Bluetooth/Wi-Fi/contacts or calendar support with native HTML 5.

Comment: what's this "wrapper" technique, can you tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously doubt it.  All of those things require permissions to use from an application and it would be too much of a security risk to allow access to them from a webpage.

Comment: GPS position can be accessed (after the user gives permission)

Answer (score 0):

That information is not available.  If you wanted to get that information, you'd have to create an application using the Android SDK.